# Memory efficient Gaussian blur using scipy.ndimage

Tags: memory-management, scipy, gis, gaussian

I am trying to Gaussian smooth large GIS datasets (10000 x 10000 arrays).  My current approach is to load the entire array into memory, smooth it, then write it back.  It looks like this:

```
big_array = band_on_disk.ReadAsArray()
scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(big_array, sigma, output=smoothed_array)
output_band.WriteArray(smoothed_array)
```

For large rasters I get a `MemoryError` so I would like to load subblocks of that array, but I am not sure how to handle the Gaussian smooth for areas that affect neighboring subblocks.

Any advice on how to fix the above algorithm so it works on a smaller memory footprint while still correctly smoothing the entire array?

Comment: Could you pass a [memory mapped](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) array to `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`?

Comment: Where does the `MemoryError` occur?  Am I correct in assuming that you've already allocated memory for `smoothed_array`, and that the error occurs when you load `big_array` from disk?

Comment: Thanks @JohnVinyard, yes it occurs when I allocate memory for big_array.  Memory mapped arrays seem to be working for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [memory mapped](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) files.

### Moderate Memory Usage and Bearably Fast

If you can afford to have *one* of your arrays in memory, this is bearably fast:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

# create some fake data, save it to disk, and free up its memory
shape = (10000,10000)
orig = np.random.random_sample(shape)
orig.tofile('orig.dat')
print 'saved original'
del orig

# allocate memory for the smoothed data
smoothed = np.zeros((10000,10000))

# memory-map the original data, so it isn't read into memory all at once
orig = np.memmap('orig.dat', np.float64, 'r', shape=shape)
print 'memmapped'

sigma = 10 # I have no idea what a reasonable value is here
gaussian_filter(orig, sigma, output = smoothed)
# save the smoothed data to disk
smoothed.tofile('smoothed.dat')
```

### Low Memory Usage and Very Slow

If you can't afford to have either array in memory all at once, you can memory-map both the original and smoothed arrays.  This has very low memory usage, but is prohibitively slow, on my machine at least.

You'll have to ignore the first part of this code, because it cheats and creates the original array all at once, and then saves it to disk.  You can replace this with code to load data that you've built incrementally on disk.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

# create some fake data, save it to disk, and free up its memory
shape = (10000,10000)
orig = np.random.random_sample(shape)
orig.tofile('orig.dat')
print 'saved original'
del orig

# memory-map the original data, so it isn't read into memory all at once
orig = np.memmap('orig.dat', np.float64, 'r', shape=shape)
# create a memory mapped array for the smoothed data
smoothed = np.memmap('smoothed.dat', np.float64, 'w+', shape = shape)
print 'memmapped'

sigma = 10 # I have no idea what a reasonable value is here
gaussian_filter(orig, sigma, output = smoothed)
```